# Task scheduler API

Tags: c#, api, scheduled-tasks

I'm spec'ing out a API for a task scheduler and I would be thankful for your thoughts. This is what I've got so far:

```
public void Configure(Context ctx) {
    // Single tasks
    ctx.Run(() => Tasks.First()).Every.Midnight;
    ctx.Run(() => Tasks.Second()).Every.Day(8,0));

    // Multiple tasks
    ctx.Run(() => {
        Tasks.Third();
        Tasks.Fourth();
    }).Every.Day(8,0);

   // Triggers:
   ..Every.Hour(20/*Minute*/);
   ..Every.Minute(10/*Second*/);
   ..Every.Second();
}
```

The run method accepts an Action parameter.

Obviously, I need to support custom triggers to allow users to configure it exactly as they want. It could be done by implementing an interface like:

```
interface ITask {
    bool ShouldRun(DateTime currentDate);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with all your various every overloads, if you want fluent style replace the everys with a single method `.AndReoccur(int numberOfTimes, Timespan interval)` also I'm pretty sure this site is supposed to be for compilable functioning code, maybe this fits on stackoverflow better?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling your own API for repetitions, I'd adopt the terminology and semantics of RFC 5545 RRULEs which is widely used within Calendaring applications

[Section 3.8.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3) thoroughly documents the syntax and behavior of RRULEs (Recurrence rules).  They look like

> ```
> RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH
> ```

which means

> Weekly on Tuesday and Thursday for five weeks:

so you could implement these semantics (or find an existing RFC 5545 library that does it) and your API might look very similar to the RRULE syntax:

```
ctx.Run(...).Freq(WEEKLY).Count(10).ByDay(TU, TH)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to be able to use a non-functional approach to running the api. Perhaps I'm a new developer and don't understand lambdas. Give me the option to go.

```
ctx.Run(//Task, or List of tasks,  //How often, //Time to start, //Possible skip conditions - maybe skip weekends);

//Utilize enums that they can use
ctx.Run(Task.First(), Frequency.Daily, Time.Midnight);

//or pass a list of tasks perhaps
List<Task> tasks;
ctx.Run(tasks, Frequency.Hourly, Time.Custom(hour, min, sec), Time.Weekends);
```